# How to make safari's tabView in document-based application?

Tags: cocoa, macos, safari, tabview

I program one app for helping Spip users to do their loop for their "Squelette", and i would put a view with tab like Safari.

How do that, in a document-Based application. I have my window whith an NSTextView where we coding and a i would add a preview in a tab in the same window.

Thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [PSMTabBarControl](http://www.positivespinmedia.com/dev/PSMTabBarControl.html).